# Why start from XSD (rather than WSDL) in contract-first SOAP-service?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, spring-ws

In this Spring reference (Chapter 3. Writing Contract-First Web Services)

http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html

it says
*"A service contract is generally expressed as a WSDL file. Note that in Spring-WS, writing the WSDL by hand is not required. Based on the XSD and some conventions, Spring-WS can create the WSDL for you..."*

That is also the approach implemented in the sample app:

https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-soap-service.git

Just wondering... if you do "contract first", WHY would you ever want to start from XSD, and let framework generate the WSDL?
I thought the idea behind "contract first" as best-practice is to give you maximum control over the interface, 
to ensure maximum compatibility between different SOAP-service frameworks, tools, languages, etc.

While the XSD contains datatypes and request/response object types, it does not define the actual service-operations (and maybe some other stuff?)...

Isn't there a risk that you will encounter incompatibilities between different tools in the stuff that is NOT defined in the XSD?

Would appreciate some clarifications on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this comparison:
https://dzone.com/articles/apache-cxf-vs-apache-axis-vs

"Isn't there a risk that you will encounter incompatibilities between different tools in the stuff that is NOT defined in the XSD?"

Basically, what Spring does is to let you define the service through code, and use the domain objects that's been generated from XSD. You won't have an issue on that side I guess.

But, from my current experience, because Spring doesn't fully compatible JAX-WS, you could have some implementation problems, especially when you're working 3rd party teams. For example, spring-ws doesn't support same named methods & property objects.

Other than that, it's pretty easy to setup and use

Comment: Umm.... What I am aiming at is, it does not really seem like contract-first, anymore.
Example: Spring generates your WSDL, and you get client-apps using it.
Later, you upgrade to a new version of Spring (or maybe slightly change your service implementation-class, or even upgrade your jdk-version?)
and it might cause some slight change in your WSDL = potential problems for some client-apps...??
This can never happen if you do pure WSDL-first....

Comment: @Rop Even if you crate your service from WSDL in the first place, you can let the underlying framework create the WSDL dynamically from your implementation later on, Jax-ws or CXf do this without spring. And then, you can modify the signatures, etc. and this will change the WSDL as well. You need to make sure not the modify the method signatures in the first place. WSDL just help you create your service in the first place, that's it. Its mainly for clients to know about your service. But I agree that spring may have change their method naming strategy in the future and that can cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason in my experience from using spring-ws. The WSDL can be generated dynamically by Spring. This is very advantageous, considering it contains the endpoint(which is different between landscapes). It is common to use base XSD's to define commonly used data elements. Also, after you define the XSD's you can use jaxb to generate the necessary class files for your source code.

As you can see, by defining the XSD's and thereby generating the class files from them. Your code base is well on its way to becoming a legitimate web service.